# Differences Between C# and VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the most important functional differences between C# and VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632/what-are-the-most-important-functional-differences-between-c-and-vb-net)

Other than syntax, what are the major differences between C# and vb.net?