# Yield in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

C# has the keyword called [yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0(VS.80).aspx). VB.NET lacks this keyword. How have the Visual Basic programmers gotten around the lack of this keyword? Do they implement they own iterator class?  Or do they try and code to avoid the need of an iterator?

The [yield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0(VS.80).aspx) keyword does force the compiler to do some coding behind the scenes. *[The implementation of iterators in C# and its consequences (part 1)](http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2008/08/12/8849519.aspx)* has a good example of that.

Comment: "VB.NET lacks this keyword." - not anymore.  For all you googlers finding this page, check out the Microsoft Async framework.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg316360 and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg497937

Comment: @mattmc3: note that requires 2012, and does not work in VS.2010

Comment: @mattmc3: the Async framework (your first link) appears to be a heavier-weight (and more complex) solution than Yield (your second link)?  Not that it matters since Yield showed up in VB at the same time. Just wanting to know the ins and outs of different approaches.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx discusses Async/Await. USING `await` is easy enough. But implementing the other side, which sources the stream of objects, looks like a lot more work than simply saying "Yield".

Comment: FYI, in VS2010 I was able to use Linq for some situations, to avoid creating large intermediate lists. `Where` and `Select`. Ex: `Dim zsEnum As IEnumerable(Of Double) = (From p In points Where p.Y > 0 Select p.Z)`, `For Each z As Double In zsEnum ...`. Because Linq creates an IEnumerable rather than a concrete list, the above doesn't consume significant extra memory. Important for huge list, in 32-bit .Net 3.5 process, to avoid fragmenting memory further.

Comment: [This newer answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48730455/199364) shows use of VB's `Yield value` (inside an `Iterator Function` declaration), which was added years after this question was asked.

Answer (score 71):

### Note: This answer is old now. Iterator blocks have since been added to [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET)

C# translates the yield keyword into a state machine at compile time. VB.NET does not have the yield keyword, but it does have its own mechanism for safely embedding state within a function that is not easily available in C#.

The C# `static` keyword is normally translated to Visual Basic using the `Shared` keyword, but there are two places where things get confusing. One is that a C# static class is really a Module in Visual Basic rather than a Shared class (you'd think they'd let you code it either way in Visual Basic, but noooo). The other is that VB.NET does have its own `Static` keyword.  However, `Static` has a different meaning in VB.NET.

You use the `Static` keyword in VB.NET to declare a variable inside a function, and when you do the variable retains its state across function calls. This is different than just declaring a private static class member in C#, because a static function member in VB.NET is guaranteed to also be thread-safe, in that the compiler translates it to use the Monitor class at compile time.

So why write all this here? Well, it should be possible to build a re-usable generic `Iterator<T>` class (or `Iterator(Of T)` in VB.NET). In this class you would implement the state machine used by C#, with `Yield()` and `Break()` methods that correspond to the C# keywords. Then you could use a static instance (in the VB.NET sense) in a function so that it can ultimately do pretty much the same job as C#'s `yield` in about the same amount of code (discarding the class implemenation itself, since it would be infinitely re-usable).

I haven't cared enough about Yield to attempt it myself, but it *should* be doable. That said, it's also far from trivial, as C# team member Eric Lippert calls this "[the most complicated transformation in the compiler](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/24/iterator-blocks-part-seven-why-no-anonymous-iterators.aspx)."

I have also come to believe since I wrote the first draft of this over a year ago that it's not really possible in a meaningful way until Visual Studio 2010 comes out, as it would require sending multiple lambdas to the Iterator class and so to be really practical we need [.NET 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework)'s support for multi-line lambdas.

Answer (score 21):

The [Async CTP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/async.aspx) includes support for `Yield` in VB.NET.

See [Iterators in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg497937) for information on usage.

And now it's included in the box with Visual Studio 2012!

Answer (score 15):

There's the nice article *[Use Iterators in VB Now](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2009/02/01/Use-Iterators-in-VB-Now.aspx?Page=2)* by Bill McCarthy in Visual Studio Magazine on emulating `yield` in VB.NET. Alternatively wait for the next version of Visual Basic.

Answer (score 5):

Fortunately now we have `Yield` return 
here is an example from my project + implementing an interface with `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(T)` function:

```
Public Class Status
    Implements IStatus

    Private _statusChangeDate As DateTime
    Public Property statusChangeDate As DateTime Implements IStatus.statusChangeDate
        Get
            Return _statusChangeDate
        End Get
        Set(value As Date)
            _statusChangeDate = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _statusId As Integer
    Public Property statusId As Integer Implements IStatus.statusId
        Get
            Return _statusId
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _statusId = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _statusName As String
    Public Property statusName As String Implements IStatus.statusName
        Get
            Return _statusName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _statusName = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Iterator Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerable(Of Object) Implements IStatus.GetEnumerator
        Yield Convert.ToDateTime(statusChangeDate)
        Yield Convert.ToInt32(statusId)
        Yield statusName.ToString()
    End Function

End Class

Public Interface IStatus
    Property statusChangeDate As DateTime
    Property statusId As Integer
    Property statusName As String
    Function GetEnumerator() As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of Object)
End Interface
```

This is how i extract all properties from outside:

```
For Each itm As SLA.IStatus In outputlist
    For Each it As Object In itm.GetEnumerator()
        Debug.Write(it & " ")
    Next
    Debug.WriteLine("")
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally just write my own iterator class that inherits from `IEnumerator(Of T)`. It does take some time to get it right, but I think in the end it's better to write it right then try to avoid it. Another method that I have done is to write a recursive method that returns `IEnumerable(Of T)` and just returns `List(Of T)` and uses `.AddRange`.

Answer (score 1):

VB.NET has the `Iterator` keyword https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/iterator

Since Visual Studio 2012 it seems

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, this will be a thing of the past with the upcoming version of VB. Since iterators are actually gaining a lot of importance with new paradigms (especially LINQ in combination with lazy evaluation), this has quite a high priority, as far as I know from Paul Vick's blog. Then again, Paul's no longer the head of the VB team and I haven't yet had time to watch the PCD talks.

Still, if you're interested, they're linked in [Paul's blog](http://www.panopticoncentral.net/archive/2008/10/31/24803.aspx).

Comment: I know this is a very old post, but Paul Vick recently reset his blog & deleted the VB content, so your link is now broken

Comment: @MarkJ I know. :-( Unfortunately, there isn’t much that can be done about this. FWIW Paul is aware of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

The below code gives the output

2, 4, 8, 16, 32

In VB.NET,

```
Public Shared Function setofNumbers() As Integer()
    Dim counter As Integer = 0
    Dim results As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim result As Integer = 1
    While counter < 5
        result = result * 2
        results.Add(result)
        counter += 1
    End While
    Return results.ToArray()
End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    For Each i As Integer In setofNumbers()
        MessageBox.Show(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

In C#

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (int i in setofNumbers())
    {
        MessageBox.Show(i.ToString());
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<int> setofNumbers()
{
    int counter=0;
    int result=1;
    while (counter < 5)
    {
        result = result * 2;
        counter += 1;
        yield return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a particularly useful answer, since the point of "yield" is for situations where it is not practical to generate the whole collection at one time. Due to memory constraints, or because the IEnumerable represents data that is actively streaming in, and need to start processing it right away.

Comment: It'd really strengthen your example if you added a noticeable thread sleep between your while loop iterations