# VB.NET equivalent to this C# linq class

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq, ienumerable

Guys, I'm trying to convert something from C# to VB.NET and I'm having trouble finding an equivlent in VB.NET to C#'s yield keyword. I realize 'yield' is not a convertable keyword to VB.NET, so can someone please show me how I would implement this code in VB.NET. I got all of it converted over except for the implemented GetEnumerator() function. It is simply a class that implements CollectionBase and IEnumerable (to make it LINQ worthy):

```
[Serializable()]
public partial class Customers : CollectionBase,    System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<BusinessLayer.Customer> 
{

    public new System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<BusinessLayer.Customer> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (BusinessLayer.Customer Cust in this.List)
        {
            yield return Cust;
        }
    }

    public Customers()
    {

    }

    public Customers(DataRowCollection datarows) : this()
    {
        this.Load(datarows);
    }
    protected void Load(DataRowCollection dataRows)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in dataRows) {
        this.Add(new Customer(dr));
    }
}

public Customer this[int index] {
    get { return (Customer)base.InnerList[index]; }
    set { base.InnerList[index] = value; }
}

public int Add(Customer val)
{
    return base.InnerList.Add(val);
}
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: You'd probably get more help from VB folks if you told them what the Yield keyword does.  For most of my 35 year carrier "Yield" meant a thread yielding it remaining CPU time to the scheduler to let any other pending threads run.  I assume that now MS is having it mean something different? (since there is a simple, long-standing VB convention for that)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97381/yield-in-vb-net

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you cannot use the `yield` keyword, you will have to implement `GetEnumerator()` another way. What you can do is return the enumerator of the `List` from `CollectionBase`. However, because this is an `IList` and not an `IList<T>`, you will have to cast it (you can use the `Cast<T>()` extension method from Linq for this). Your C# code then becomes:

```
public IEnumerator<BusinessLayer.Customer> GetEnumerator()
{
    return InnerList.Cast<BusinessLayer.Customer>().GetEnumerator();
}
```

This gives the same result, but behaves in a *slightly* different way (with regards to no longer using the delayed execution of `yield`).

In VB.Net, `GetEnumerator()` would be:

```
Public Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator(Of BusinessLayer.Customer)
    Return InnerList.Cast(Of BusinessLayer.Customer)().GetEnumerator()
End Function
```

The rest of your code should translate directly to VB.Net.

Answer (score 1):

Either wait for the next version of VB.NET, or consult [this nice article](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2009/02/01/use-iterators-in-vb-now.aspx) by Bill McCarthy in Visual Studio magazine.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since you asked the question, but I was having the same problem of not having a 'yield' keyword in VB.  This is what I found and have been using in its stead.  You can implement 'yield' with a GenericIterator, here is code for such an Iterator:

```
    Public Class GenericIterator(Of T)
    Implements IEnumerable(Of T)
    Implements IEnumerator(Of T)

    Public Delegate Function MoveNextFunc(ByRef nextItem As T) As Boolean

    Private _Current As T
    Private _func As MoveNextFunc

    Public Sub New(ByVal func As MoveNextFunc)
        _func = func
    End Sub


    Public Function MoveNext() As Boolean Implements IEnumerator.MoveNext
        Return _func(_Current)
    End Function


    Public Function GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator(Of T) Implements IEnumerable(Of T).GetEnumerator
        Static iBeenCalled As Int32
        If (iBeenCalled = 0) AndAlso _
           (Threading.Interlocked.Increment(iBeenCalled) = 1) Then
            Return Me
        Else
            Return New GenericIterator(Of T)(_func)
        End If
    End Function


    Public ReadOnly Property Current() As T Implements IEnumerator(Of T).Current
        Get
            Return _Current
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Overridable Sub Reset() Implements IEnumerator.Reset
        Throw New NotImplementedException("Iterator cannot be reset")
    End Sub


    Private Function IEnumerator_GetEnumerator() As IEnumerator Implements IEnumerable.GetEnumerator
        Return Me.GetEnumerator
    End Function

    Private ReadOnly Property IEnumerator_Current() As Object Implements IEnumerator.Current
        Get
            Return Me.Current
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
        ' not implemented
    End Sub

End Class
```

Once you have this class you can implement 'yield' similar to how it's done in this sample Zip extension function:

```
Public Module IEnumerableExtensions

    <Extension()>
    Public Function Zip(Of T1, T2)(ByVal left As IEnumerable(Of T1), ByVal right As IEnumerable(Of T2)) As IEnumerable(Of Pair(Of T1, T2))
        Dim leftG As IEnumerator(Of T1) = left.Select(Function(x) x).GetEnumerator()
        Dim rightG As IEnumerator(Of T2) = right.Select(Function(x) x).GetEnumerator()
        Return New GenericIterator(Of Pair(Of T1, T2)) _
            (Function(ByRef x) As Boolean
                 Dim canMove As Boolean = leftG.MoveNext() AndAlso rightG.MoveNext()
                 x = New Pair(Of T1, T2)(leftG.Current, rightG.Current)
                 Return canMove
             End Function)
    End Function

End Module
```

The lambda function has a single by ref parameter which you are supposed to save your return value to.

It is worth noting that I called the selects on leftG and rightG because the compiler was complaining about how some IEumerables like {"foo", "bar"} had already materialized.  The select calls naturally removed the materialization.
It is also worth noting that for the extension function to work properly you need to import `System.Runtime.CompilerServices`.  For the Iterator you need `System.Collections.Generic`.  And in general you obviously need `System.Linq`.
It is also worth noting that in the above function 'Pair' is:

```
Public Class Pair(Of T1, T2)
    Public Property First As T1
    Public Property Second As T2

    Public Sub New(ByVal f As T1, ByVal s As T2)
        First = f
        Second = s
    End Sub
End Class
```

I hope this helps your conversion efforts in some way!  Good luck!

Comment: I appreciate the answer. Adrian's answer worked for what I needed though.