# Find common prefix of strings

Tags: c#, string, pattern-matching

I am having 4 strings:

```
"h:/a/b/c"
"h:/a/b/d"
"h:/a/b/e"
"h:/a/c"
```

I want to find the common prefix for those strings, i.e. `"h:/a"`.
How to find that?

Usually I'd split the string with delimiter `'/'` and put it in another list, and so on.
Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: do you mean you want to find any strings that are common for all; or that there will only be one string common for all?

Comment: h:/ is a drive? limit the data input can give you a better answer that fits your need.

Comment: I have clarified the question to how I understand it. Please rollback if this is wrong.

Comment: Andras,
i want one string common for all..

Comment: The longest common prefix is `h:/a/`

Answer (score 37):

```
string[] xs = new[] { "h:/a/b/c", "h:/a/b/d", "h:/a/b/e", "h:/a/c" };

string x = string.Join("/", xs.Select(s => s.Split('/').AsEnumerable())
                              .Transpose()
                              .TakeWhile(s => s.All(d => d == s.First()))
                              .Select(s => s.First()));
```

with

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Transpose<T>(
    this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source)
{
    var enumerators = source.Select(e => e.GetEnumerator()).ToArray();
    try
    {
        while (enumerators.All(e => e.MoveNext()))
        {
            yield return enumerators.Select(e => e.Current).ToArray();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Array.ForEach(enumerators, e => e.Dispose());
    }
}
```

Comment: If you remove the `Split` it works with individual characters as well.

Comment: A clever functional approach! Thanks for the contribution, dtb -- it's always fun reading your take.

Comment: hey it is showing error in the transpose method...
tell me the namespaces to include..

Comment: There is no `Transpose` method in the .NET framework. I used the following implementation; had to change one the `First` calls to `FirstOrDefault` to make it work though: http://www.extensionmethod.net/Details.aspx?ID=152

Comment: I've added my own implementation of a `Transpose` extension method.

Comment: You need a .ToArray() after the final Select otherwise the Join method doesn't work.

Comment: OK, in .Net 4 you don't, .Net 3.5 you do:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join(VS.90).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.join.aspx

Comment: @dtb: Is there a VB.Net version of it? cause yield keyword is not there in VB.Net.

Comment: @dtb I got a YSOD from your link http://www.extensionmethod.net/Details.aspx?ID=152 fyi

Comment: Note that Transpose implementation will enter infinite loop if passed empty collection (All returns true for empty collections). Besides, implementation contains potential memory leak - one of GetEnumerator methods may throw, and all previously opened enumerators will remain undisposed.

Comment: This pretty awful really.  I realize it was written at the height of "Linq mania" but there are both simpler and better performing solutions I would choose over this.  For example see the accepted answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33709165/get-common-prefix-of-two-string   Just call it over your list for each entry with the previous common prefix passed each time.  EDIT or see the GetCommonPrefix() answer also on that page.

Comment: I find this solution hard to read (not being well versed with LINQ) and would appreciate if someone edited it to explain what it's doing and why. @db
(I'm intersted, even if "there are simpler and better performing solutions" as per the last comment by @Ash)

Answer (score 28):

A short LINQy solution of mine (using `MinBy` from .NET 6).

```
var samples = new[] { "h:/a/b/c", "h:/a/b/d", "h:/a/b/e", "h:/a/e" };
    
var commonPrefix = new string(samples.MinBy(s => s.Length)
        .TakeWhile((c, i) => samples.All(s => s[i] == c)).ToArray());
```

For .NET 5 and older use this:

```
var samples = new[] { "h:/a/b/c", "h:/a/b/d", "h:/a/b/e", "h:/a/e" };
    
var commonPrefix = new string(
    samples.First().Substring(0, samples.Min(s => s.Length))
    .TakeWhile((c, i) => samples.All(s => s[i] == c)).ToArray());
```

Comment: Nice and short solution and far easier to understand than all the others.

Comment: `.First().Substring(0, samples.Min(s => s.Length))` can be replaced with `.Min()` in this case.

Comment: It seems to me that the idea here is to get the shortest string in the list. `.Min()` does not necessarily get the shortest string. `{"aa", "b"}.Min()` returns "aa", since "a" sorts lower/earlier than "b".

Comment: @NikoO It doesn't have to be the shortest string though. It can be any string that won't go out of range at `s[i]`. Alex's clever `Min()` suggestion satisfies the condition and makes code even more concise. That said, searching for the minimum string has to be more expensive than searching for the shortest one. In .NET 6, I would go with `MinBy(s => s.Length)`.

Answer (score 15):

Just loop round the characters of the shortest string and compare each character to the character in the same position in the other strings.  Whilst they all match keep going.  As soon as one doesn't match then the string up to the current position -1 is the answer.

Something like (pseudo code)

```
int count=0;
foreach(char c in shortestString)
{
    foreach(string s in otherStrings)
    {
        if (s[count]!=c)
        {
             return shortestString.SubString(0,count-1); //need to check count is not 0 
        }
    }
    count+=1;
 }
 return shortestString;
```

Comment: but if i have some 20 strings.. do u think the comparison of the shortest with others char by char is effecient?

Comment: If you only have 20 strings I don't think you need to worry about efficiency, but I'm not sure what more you can do as you need to check every string to make sure they are the same.  you might be able to do it better if you know if the strings likely to be common for some amount.

Comment: @deepasundari - If you need to find the first different character in the strings, then the minimum number of characters you can compare is the ones that are the same at the start in each string, plus one that is different in one string. So this is provably the most efficient algorithm to find a common prefix.

Comment: no problem. I would be interested in a profiled comparison with dtb's answer, that might be more efficient on a multiple processor machine.  You should also accept an answer.

Comment: **NOTE** here that the naming here identifies an important dependency that the parent `foreach` loop actually contains the `shortestString`, otherwise you'll get an `index out of bounds` exception when accessing `sub[count]` whenever `sub.Length == count` - If you can't guarantee that, just add a check in your method to return early.... `if (sub.Length == count) return parent.Substring(0, count);` inside of the inner foreach loop

Answer (score 7):

Working code based on Sam Holder's solution (note it gives h:/a/ not h:/a as the longest common initial substring in the question):

```
using System;

namespace CommonPrefix
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(CommonPrefix(new[] { "h:/a/b/c", "h:/a/b/d", "h:/a/b/e", "h:/a/c" })); // "h:/a/"
            Console.WriteLine(CommonPrefix(new[] { "abc", "abc" })); // "abc"
            Console.WriteLine(CommonPrefix(new[] { "abc" })); // "abc"
            Console.WriteLine(CommonPrefix(new string[] { })); // ""
            Console.WriteLine(CommonPrefix(new[] { "a", "abc" })); // "a"
            Console.WriteLine(CommonPrefix(new[] { "abc", "a" })); // "a"

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static string CommonPrefix(string[] ss)
        {
            if (ss.Length == 0)
            {
                return "";
            }

            if (ss.Length == 1)
            {
                return ss[0];
            }

            int prefixLength = 0;

            foreach (char c in ss[0])
            {
                foreach (string s in ss)
                {
                    if (s.Length <= prefixLength || s[prefixLength] != c)
                    {
                        return ss[0].Substring(0, prefixLength);
                    }
                }
                prefixLength++;
            }

            return ss[0]; // all strings identical up to length of ss[0]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A minor point - your comment on the return statement at the bottom of your code states 'all strings identical'.  That is not true.  The test performed by this function only is testing if the root of the other strings in the array ss match ss[0] up to the length of ss[0].  Other strings in the array ss may be longer than ss[0].  Nevertheless the code is performing the required task correctly by my eye.

Answer (score 5):

This is the [**longest common substring**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem) problem (although it's a slightly specialized case since you appear to only care about the prefix). There's no library implementation of the algorithm in the .NET platform that you can call directly, but the article linked here is chock-full of steps on how you'd do it yourself.

Comment: i dont think that logic will work out here...

i just want to trace from first and stop when the difference comes

Comment: I gave this a +1 because the original question did not ask for a prefix, it just asked for the common substring (presumably we were supposed to infer if was a prefix from the data, but it was not what was asked).

Comment: Given that only a common prefix is searched, the general longest common substring algorithm would be a terrible overkill (O(n^2) vs. O(n) for only two strings ...). The problem is NOT a "slightly specialized case" but a much easier to solve one :-). Usually, I would give -1 (in order to bring the correct answer up), but given that the question was rephrased, I'll just leave it :-) ...

Comment: @MartinStettner I don't think you should vote down answers to bring the answer you consider correct up.  You should down vote answers you think are wrong, and upvote answers you think are correct. If enough people agree with you the answers will rise to the top naturally. The correct answer will be at the top, assuming it is marked as accepted.

Comment: I like that you brought the question (original or otherwise) into a broader perspective. Of course, I also like having an opinion on this answer, and apparently, I'm in good company. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I wanted a common string prefix, except I wanted to include any character (like /) and I did not want something performant/fancy just something I can read with tests.  So I have this: https://github.com/fschwiet/DreamNJasmine/commit/ad802611ceacc673f2d03c30f7c8199f552b586f

```
public class CommonStringPrefix
{
    public static string Of(IEnumerable<string> strings)
    {
        var commonPrefix = strings.FirstOrDefault() ?? "";

        foreach(var s in strings)
        {
            var potentialMatchLength = Math.Min(s.Length, commonPrefix.Length);

            if (potentialMatchLength < commonPrefix.Length)
                commonPrefix = commonPrefix.Substring(0, potentialMatchLength);

            for(var i = 0; i < potentialMatchLength; i++)
            {
                if (s[i] != commonPrefix[i])
                {
                    commonPrefix = commonPrefix.Substring(0, i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return commonPrefix;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a custom implementation of the trie algorithm in c# (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).
It is used to perform an indexed string via prefixes. This class has O(1) write and reads for leaf nodes. For prefix searches, the performance is O(log n), however the count of results for prefix is O(1).

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class StringIndex
{
    private Dictionary<char, Item> _rootChars;

    public StringIndex()
    {
        _rootChars = new Dictionary<char, Item>();
    }

    public void Add(string value, string data)
    {
        int level = 0;
        Dictionary<char, Item> currentChars = _rootChars;
        Item currentItem = null;

        foreach (char c in value)
        {
            if (currentChars.ContainsKey(c))
            {
                currentItem = currentChars[c];
            }
            else
            {
                currentItem = new Item() { Level = level, Letter = c };
                currentChars.Add(c, currentItem);                
            }

            currentChars = currentItem.Items;

            level++;
        }

        if (!currentItem.Values.Contains(data))
        {
            currentItem.Values.Add(data);
            IncrementCount(value);
        }
    }

    private void IncrementCount(string value)
    {
        Dictionary<char, Item> currentChars = _rootChars;
        Item currentItem = null;

        foreach (char c in value)
        {
            currentItem = currentChars[c];
            currentItem.Total++;
            currentChars = currentItem.Items;
        }
    }

    public void Remove(string value, string data)
    {
        Dictionary<char, Item> currentChars = _rootChars;
        Dictionary<char, Item> parentChars = null;
        Item currentItem = null;

        foreach (char c in value)
        {
            if (currentChars.ContainsKey(c))
            {
                currentItem = currentChars[c];
                parentChars = currentChars;
                currentChars = currentItem.Items;
            }
            else
            {
                return; // no matches found
            }
        }

        if (currentItem.Values.Contains(data))
        {
            currentItem.Values.Remove(data);
            DecrementCount(value);
            if (currentItem.Total == 0)
            {
                parentChars.Remove(currentItem.Letter);
            }
        }
    }

    private void DecrementCount(string value)
    {
        Dictionary<char, Item> currentChars = _rootChars;
        Item currentItem = null;

        foreach (char c in value)
        {
            currentItem = currentChars[c];
            currentItem.Total--;
            currentChars = currentItem.Items;
        }
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        _rootChars.Clear();
    }

    public int GetValuesByPrefixCount(string prefix)
    {
        int valuescount = 0;

        int level = 0;
        Dictionary<char, Item> currentChars = _rootChars;
        Item currentItem = null;

        foreach (char c in prefix)
        {
            if (currentChars.ContainsKey(c))
            {
                currentItem = currentChars[c];
                currentChars = currentItem.Items;
            }
            else
            {
                return valuescount; // no matches found
            }
            level++;
        }

        valuescount = currentItem.Total;

        return valuescount;
    }

    public HashSet<string> GetValuesByPrefixFlattened(string prefix)
    {
        var results = GetValuesByPrefix(prefix);
        return new HashSet<string>(results.SelectMany(x => x));
    }

    public List<HashSet<string>> GetValuesByPrefix(string prefix)
    {
        var values = new List<HashSet<string>>();

        int level = 0;
        Dictionary<char, Item> currentChars = _rootChars;
        Item currentItem = null;

        foreach (char c in prefix)
        {
            if (currentChars.ContainsKey(c))
            {
                currentItem = currentChars[c];
                currentChars = currentItem.Items;
            }
            else
            {
                return values; // no matches found
            }
            level++;
        }

        ExtractValues(values, currentItem);

        return values;
    }

    public void ExtractValues(List<HashSet<string>> values, Item item)
    {
        foreach (Item subitem in item.Items.Values)
        {
            ExtractValues(values, subitem);
        }

        values.Add(item.Values);
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public int Level { get; set; }
        public char Letter { get; set; }
        public int Total { get; set; }
        public HashSet<string> Values { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<char, Item> Items { get; set; }

        public Item()
        {
            Values = new HashSet<string>();
            Items = new Dictionary<char, Item>();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the unit testing & example code for how to use this class.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

    [TestClass]
    public class StringIndexTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void AddAndSearchValues()
        {

            var si = new StringIndex();

            si.Add("abcdef", "1");
            si.Add("abcdeff", "2");
            si.Add("abcdeffg", "3");
            si.Add("bcdef", "4");
            si.Add("bcdefg", "5");
            si.Add("cdefg", "6");
            si.Add("cdefgh", "7");

            var output = si.GetValuesByPrefixFlattened("abc");

            Assert.IsTrue(output.Contains("1") && output.Contains("2") && output.Contains("3"));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void RemoveAndSearch()
        {

            var si = new StringIndex();

            si.Add("abcdef", "1");
            si.Add("abcdeff", "2");
            si.Add("abcdeffg", "3");
            si.Add("bcdef", "4");
            si.Add("bcdefg", "5");
            si.Add("cdefg", "6");
            si.Add("cdefgh", "7");

            si.Remove("abcdef", "1");

            var output = si.GetValuesByPrefixFlattened("abc");

            Assert.IsTrue(!output.Contains("1") && output.Contains("2") && output.Contains("3"));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void Clear()
        {

            var si = new StringIndex();

            si.Add("abcdef", "1");
            si.Add("abcdeff", "2");
            si.Add("abcdeffg", "3");
            si.Add("bcdef", "4");
            si.Add("bcdefg", "5");
            si.Add("cdefg", "6");
            si.Add("cdefgh", "7");

            si.Clear();
            var output = si.GetValuesByPrefix("abc");

            Assert.IsTrue(output.Count == 0);
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public void AddAndSearchValuesCount()
        {

            var si = new StringIndex();

            si.Add("abcdef", "1");
            si.Add("abcdeff", "2");
            si.Add("abcdeffg", "3");
            si.Add("bcdef", "4");
            si.Add("bcdefg", "5");
            si.Add("cdefg", "6");
            si.Add("cdefgh", "7");

            si.Remove("cdefgh", "7");

            var output1 = si.GetValuesByPrefixCount("abc");
            var output2 = si.GetValuesByPrefixCount("b");
            var output3 = si.GetValuesByPrefixCount("bc");
            var output4 = si.GetValuesByPrefixCount("ca");

            Assert.IsTrue(output1 == 3 && output2 == 2 && output3 == 2 && output4 == 0);
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions on how to improve this class are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be, take the first string.
Get letter by letter while all the other string got the same letter on the same index position and stop if there is no match.
Remove the last character if it's a separator.

```
var str_array = new string[]{"h:/a/b/c",
         "h:/a/b/d",
         "h:/a/b/e",
         "h:/a/c"};
var separator = '/';

// get longest common prefix (optinally use ToLowerInvariant)
var ret = str_array.Any() 
    ? str_array.First().TakeWhile((s,i) => 
         str_array.All(e => 
            Char.ToLowerInvariant(s) == Char.ToLowerInvariant(e.Skip(i).Take(1).SingleOrDefault()))) 
    : String.Empty;

// remove last character if it's a separator (optional)
if (ret.LastOrDefault() == separator) 
    ret = ret.Take(ret.Count() -1);

string prefix = new String(ret.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to look for the longest common prefix in dissimilar strings.  I came up with:

```
private string FindCommonPrefix(List<string> list)
{
    List<string> prefixes = null;
    for (int len = 1; ; ++len)
    {
        var x = list.Where(s => s.Length >= len)
                    .GroupBy(c => c.Substring(0,len))
                    .Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)
                    .Select(grp => grp.Key)
                    .ToList();

        if (!x.Any())
        {
            break;
        }
        //  Copy last list
        prefixes = new List<string>(x);
    }

    return prefixes == null ? string.Empty : prefixes.First();
}
```

If there is more than one prefix with the same length, it arbitrarily returns the first one found.  Also it's case-sensitive.  Both these points can be addressed by the reader!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this ICollection extension to find the longest common base Uri from a collection of web addresses.

As it only check the collection of strings at every slash it will be a bit faster that a generic prefix routine (Not counting my inefficient algorithm!). It's verbose, but easy to follow...my favourite type of code ;-)

Ignores 'http://' and 'https://', as well as case.

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Resolves a common base Uri from a list of Uri strings. Ignores case. Includes the last slash
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="collectionOfUriStrings"></param>
    /// <returns>Common root in lowercase</returns>
    public static string GetCommonUri(this ICollection<string> collectionOfUriStrings)
    {
        //Check that collection contains entries
        if (!collectionOfUriStrings.Any())
            return string.Empty;
        //Check that the first is no zero length
        var firstUri = collectionOfUriStrings.FirstOrDefault();
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstUri))
            return string.Empty;

        //set starting position to be passed '://'
        int previousSlashPos = firstUri.IndexOf("://", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) + 2;
        int minPos = previousSlashPos + 1; //results return must have a slash after this initial position
        int nextSlashPos = firstUri.IndexOf("/", previousSlashPos + 1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        //check if any slashes
        if (nextSlashPos == -1)
            return string.Empty;

        do
        {               
            string common = firstUri.Substring(0, nextSlashPos + 1);
            //check against whole collection
            foreach (var collectionOfUriString in collectionOfUriStrings)
            {
                if (!collectionOfUriString.StartsWith(common, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    //return as soon as a mismatch is found
                    return previousSlashPos > minPos ? firstUri.Substring(0, previousSlashPos + 1).ToLower() : string.Empty ;
                }
            }
            previousSlashPos = nextSlashPos;                
            nextSlashPos = firstUri.IndexOf("/", previousSlashPos + 1, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        } while (nextSlashPos != -1);

        return previousSlashPos > minPos ? firstUri.Substring(0, previousSlashPos + 1).ToLower() : string.Empty;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to the party, but I'll give my 2 cents:

```
public static String CommonPrefix(String str, params String[] more)
{
    var prefixLength = str
                      .TakeWhile((c, i) => more.All(s => i < s.Length && s[i] == c))
                      .Count();

    return str.Substring(0, prefixLength);
}
```

Explanation:

- This works by walking through the chars of `str` as long as `All` the other strings have the same char `c` at index `i`.
- The signature split in `String` and `params String[]` ensures that at least one string is provided, no runtime checks needed.
- If called with only one string, the function will return the input (a string is its own prefix).
- It's cheaper to `Count` the prefix length and return `Substring(0, prefixLength)` than to reassemble the enumerated chars by means of `String.Join()` or `Enumerable.Aggregate()`

Answer (score 1):

```
public string LongestCommonPrefix(string[] strs)
{
    return strs.Aggregate((seed,z) => string.Join("",seed.TakeWhile((v,i)=> z.Length > i && v == z[i])));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I implemented quite efficient method when you must analyse huge amount of strings, I'm caching counts and lengths here as well which improves performance by about 1,5x on my tests comparing to properties access in loops:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

........

public static string GetCommonPrefix ( IList<string> strings )
{
    var stringsCount = strings.Count;
    if( stringsCount == 0 )
        return null;
    if( stringsCount == 1 )
        return strings[0];

    var sb = new StringBuilder( strings[0] );
    string str;
    int i, j, sbLen, strLen;

    for( i = 1; i < stringsCount; i++ )
    {
        str = strings[i];

        sbLen = sb.Length;
        strLen = str.Length;
        if( sbLen > strLen )
            sb.Length = sbLen = strLen;

        for( j = 0; j < sbLen; j++ )
        {
            if( sb[j] != str[j] )
            {
                sb.Length = j;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

**UPD:**
I also implemented parallel version which uses above method as final step:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

........

public static string GetCommonPrefixParallel ( IList<string> strings )
{
    var stringsCount = strings.Count;
    if( stringsCount == 0 )
        return null;
    if( stringsCount == 1 )
        return strings[0];

    var firstStr = strings[0];
    var finalList = new List<string>();
    var finalListLock = new object();

    Parallel.For( 1, stringsCount,
        () => new StringBuilder( firstStr ),
        ( i, loop, localSb ) =>
        {
            var sbLen = localSb.Length;
            var str = strings[i];
            var strLen = str.Length;
            if( sbLen > strLen )
                localSb.Length = sbLen = strLen;

            for( int j = 0; j < sbLen; j++ )
            {
                if( localSb[j] != str[j] )
                {
                    localSb.Length = j;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return localSb;
        },
        ( localSb ) =>
        {
            lock( finalListLock )
            {
                finalList.Add( localSb.ToString() );
            }
        } );

    return GetCommonPrefix( finalList );
}
```

GetCommonPrefixParallel() boosts twice comparing to GetCommonPrefix() on huge strings amount and when strings length is significant. On small arrays with short strings GetCommonPrefix() works a little better. I tested on MacBook Pro Retina 13''.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple method that finds common string prefix.

```
public static string GetCommonStartingPath(string[] keys)
        {
            Array.Sort(keys, StringComparer.InvariantCulture);
            string a1 = keys[0], a2 = keys[keys.Length - 1];
            int L = a1.Length, i = 0;
            while (i < L && a1[i] == a2[i])
            {
                i++;
            }

            string result = a1.Substring(0, i);

            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

An improvement on Yegor's answer

```
var samples = new[] { "h:/a/b/c", "h:/a/b/d", "h:/a/b/e", "h:/a/e" };

var commonPrefix = new string(
    samples.Min().TakeWhile((c, i) => samples.All(s => s[i] == c)).ToArray());
```

First we know that the longest common prefix cannot be longer than the shortest element. So take the shortest one and take chars from it while all other strings have the same char at the same position. In the extreme case we take all chars from the shortest element.
By iterating over the shortest element the index lookup will not throw any exceptions.

Another (worse but still interesting) way to solve it using LINQ would be this:

```
samples.Aggregate(samples.Min(), (current, next) => new string(current.TakeWhile((c,i) => next[i] == c).ToArray() ));
```

This one works by creating a commonPrefix and comparing that to each element one by one. In each comparison the commonPrefix is either maintained or decreased. In the first iteration current is the min element, but each iteration after that it is the best commonPrefix found so far. Think of this as a depth first solution while the first one is a breadth first.

This type of solution might be improved upon by sorting the samples in terms of length so that the shortest elements are compared first.

This type of solution cannot really be better than the first however. In the best case this is as-good as the first solution. But otherwise it will do extra work by finding temporary commonPrefixes that are longer than necessary.

Answer (score -1):

Top answer can be improved to ignore case:

```
.TakeWhile(s =>
  {
      var reference = s.First();
      return s.All(d => string.Equals(reference, d, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
  })
```