# building median for each string in IList<IDictionary<string, double>>

Tags: c#, linq

Actually i have a little brain bender and and just can't find the right direction to get it to work:

Given is an `IList<IDictionary<string, double>>` and it is filled as followed:

```
Name|Value
----+-----
"x" | 3.8
"y" | 4.2
"z" | 1.5
----+-----
"x" | 7.2
"y" | 2.9
"z" | 1.3
----+-----
... | ...
```

To fill this up with some random data i used the following methods:

```
var list = CreateRandomPoints(new string[] { "x", "y", "z" }, 20);
```

This will work as followed:

```
private IList<IDictionary<string, double>> CreateRandomPoints(string[] variableNames, int count)
{
    var list = new List<IDictionary<string, double>>(count);
    list.AddRange(CreateRandomPoints(variableNames).Take(count));

    return list;
}

private IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, double>> CreateRandomPoints(string[] variableNames)
{
    while (true)
        yield return CreateRandomLine(variableNames);
}

private IDictionary<string, double> CreateRandomLine(string[] variableNames)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, double>(variableNames.Length);

    foreach (var variable in variableNames)
    {
        dict.Add(variable, _Rand.NextDouble() * 10);
    }

    return dict;
}
```

Also i can say that it is already ensured that **every Dictionary within the list contains the same keys** (but from list to list the names and count of the keys can change).

So that's what i got. Now to the things i need:

I'd like to get the median (or any other math aggregate operation) of each Key within all the dictionaries, so that my function to call would look something like:

```
IDictionary<string, double> GetMedianOfRows(this IList<IDictionary<string, double>> list)
```

The best would be to give some kind of aggregate operation as a parameter to the function to make it more generic (don't know if the func has the correct parameters, but should imagine what i'd like to do):

```
private IDictionary<string, double> Aggregate(this IList<IDictionary<string, double>> list, Func<IEnumerable<double>, double> aggregator)
```

Also my actual biggest problem is to do the job **with a single iteration** over the list, cause if within the list are 20 variables with 1000 values i don't like to iterate 20 times over the list. Instead i would go one time over the list and compute all twenty variables at once (The biggest advantage of doing it that way would be to use this also as `IEnumerable<T>` on any part of the list in a later step).

So here is the code i already got:

```
public static IDictionary<string, double> GetMedianOfRows(this IList<IDictionary<string, double>> list)
{
    //Check of parameters is left out!

    //Get first item for initialization of result dictionary
    var firstItem = list[0];

    //Create result dictionary and fill in variable names
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, double>(firstItem.Count);

    //Iterate over the whole list
    foreach (IDictionary<string, double> row in list)
    {
        //Iterate over each key/value pair within the list
        foreach (var kvp in row)
        {
            //How to determine median of all values?
        }
    }

    return dict;
}
```

Just to be sure here is a little explanation about [the Median](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median).

#### Solution

Thanks to dtb for his extension method. It was the missing part i had.

With it we can now do such beautiful statements like:

```
var result0 = list.Cast<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, double>>>()
                  .Transpose()
                  .ToDictionary(column => column.First().Key,
                                column => column.Select(kvp => kvp.Value)
                                                .Sum());
```

or

```
var result1 = list.Cast<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, double>>>()
                  .Transpose()
                  .ToDictionary(column => column.First().Key,
                                          //Performing my own function on the IEnumerable<double>
                                column => GetSumOfElements(column.Select(kvp => kvp.Value)));

private double GetSumOfElements(IEnumerable<double> elements)
{
    double result = 0;

    foreach (var element in elements)
    {
        result += element;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: If the IList contains dictionaries that all have the same keys, why not just use IList<double[]>?

Comment: cause the names can change and need to be within this structure. Another way would also be `IDictionary<string, IList<double>>`, but this leads to other problems in other scenarios. So there is no perfect solution, but we think that this will work best for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var list = CreateRandomPoints(new string[] { "x", "y", "z" }, 20);

var result = list.Cast<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, double>>>()
                 .Transpose()
                 .ToDictionary(row => row.First().Key,
                               row => row.Select(kvp => kvp.Value).Median());
```

with `Transpose` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070356/find-common-prefix-of-strings/2070434#2070434), and `Median` from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc981895.aspx).

Just to be sure here is a little explanation about the [transpose of a matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose). :-)