# Relative path in c#

Tags: c#, ftp, relative-path, absolute-path, directoryinfo

I was looking for a way to get a relative directory and file path (both) either directly or from a full path. It seems I cannot find a satisfying answer... and I googled a lot.

The problem is that I need to upload files on FTP and i need the format "Hostftp:port/"+"Directory/subdirectory" to create the ftp request

Example

```
myftp:8008/Users
myftp:8008/Users/Data
myftp:8008/Users/Data/Anagraphics
myftp:8008/Work
```

etc etc.

I pick the files from my computer so they are like

```
C:\users\MyPc\UsersData\Users
C:\users\MyPc\UsersData\Users\Data
C:\users\MyPc\UsersData\Users\Data\Anagraphics
C:\users\MyPc\UsersData\Work
```

I want them listed like

```
Users
Users\Data
Users\Data\Anagraphics
Work
```

so I can concatenate the string and make

```
myftp:8008/Users
myftp:8008/Users/Data
myftp:8008/Users/Data/Anagraphics
myftp:8008/Work
```

How to do it???

Comment: It is not very clear what you are asking. Please edit you question to provide more clear examples, and improve your formatting so it can easily be read and understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<string> paths = new List<string>()
{
    @"C:\users\MyPc\UsersData\Users",
    @"C:\users\MyPc\UsersData\Users\Data",
    @"C:\users\MyPc\UsersData\Users\Data\Anagraphics",
    @"C:\users\MyPc\UsersData\Work"
};

var MatchingChars =
  from len in Enumerable.Range(0, paths.Min(s => s.Length)).Reverse()
  let possibleMatch = paths.First().Substring(0, len)
  where paths.All(f => f.StartsWith(possibleMatch))
  select possibleMatch;

var LongestDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(MatchingChars.First());
var ftpPaths = paths.Select(p=>Path.Combine("myftp:8008",p.Substring(LongestDir.Length +1)).Replace(@"\", "/"));
```

**ftpPaths :**

```
myftp:8008/Users 
myftp:8008/Users/Data 
myftp:8008/Users/Data/Anagraphics 
myftp:8008/Work
```

To Find the common file path from list of paths I used one of answer of [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578110/how-to-extract-common-file-path-from-list-of-file-paths-in-c-sharp)