# How to remove duplicate domain emailaddress from emailaddress ArrayList

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, arraylist, email-address

I have an `ArrayList` of email addresses. I want to remove duplicates from it.

For example my array list is:

> - abc@gmail.com
> - xyz@gmail.com
> - abc@yahoo.com
> - asd@yahoo.com

I want output like this

> - abc@gmail.com
> - abc@yahoo.com

Comment: Which address should remain? The first one?

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: Post a minimal code fragment of your problem. Have a look at [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).

Comment: @user1781290,  I need any distinct domain of this email address list

Comment: There are actually no dulplicates in the example you gave. Do you mean *Select all email addresses that have the same name?*

Comment: @Prashant Pimpale, I didn't getting any logic of this query

Comment: @preciousbetine, Domain should not be duplicate in whole list, that's my query.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33849021/interleave-an-array-of-email-addresses-avoiding-items-with-same-domain-to-be-con Including your own logic!

Comment: Side note: these days, I'd recommend **against** using `ArrayList` - use a `List<string>` instead, this avoids having to constantly box and unbox values to and from `object` for each access.....

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I reviewed the question. It is different somehow.

Comment: @SalahAkbari yes that's why added this: `Including your own logic` for OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
ArrayList arr = new ArrayList { "abc@gmail.com", "xyz@gmail.com", 
                                     "abc@yahoo.com", "asd@yahoo.com" };

var res = arr.ToArray().GroupBy(c => c.ToString().Split('@')[1])
                       .Select(c=> c.FirstOrDefault()).ToArray();
```

I used an `ArrayList` to adjust with your question, but it would be better to use a `List` or `Array` of `string` instead.