# Code to collapse duplicate and semi-duplicate records?

Tags: c#, linq, distinct

I have a list of models of this type:

```
public class TourDude {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my list:

```
    public IEnumerable<TourDude> GetAllGuides {
        get {
            List<TourDude> guides = new List<TourDude>();
            guides.Add(new TourDude() { Name = "Dave Et", Id = 1 });
            guides.Add(new TourDude() { Name = "Dave Eton", Id = 1 });
            guides.Add(new TourDude() { Name = "Dave EtZ5", Id = 1 });
            guides.Add(new TourDude() { Name = "Danial Maze A", Id = 2 });
            guides.Add(new TourDude() { Name = "Danial Maze B", Id = 2 });
            guides.Add(new TourDude() { Name = "Danial", Id = 3 });
            return guides;

        }
    }
```

I want to retrieve these records:

```
{ Name = "Dave Et", Id = 1 } 
{ Name = "Danial Maze", Id = 2 }
{ Name = "Danial", Id = 3 }
```

The goal mainly to collapse duplicates and near duplicates (confirmable by the ID), taking the shortest possible value (when compared) as name.

Where do I start? Is there a complete LINQ that will do this for me? Do I need to code up an equality comparer?

**Edit 1:**

```
        var result = from x in GetAllGuides
                     group x.Name by x.Id into g
                     select new TourDude {
                         Test = Exts.LongestCommonPrefix(g),
                         Id = g.Key,
                     };

        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<char>> test = result.First().Test;

        string str = test.First().ToString();
```

Comment: AFAIK nothing built-in will do this. You might want to group by Id and then write your own code to find the Name you want to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to group the items by `Id` and then find the longest common prefix of the `Name`s within each group, then you can do so as follows:

```
var result = from x in guides
             group x.Name by x.Id into g
             select new TourDude
             {
                 Name = LongestCommonPrefix(g),
                 Id = g.Key,
             };
```

using the algorithm for finding the longest common prefix from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2070434/76217).

*Result:*

```
{ Name = "Dave Et", Id = 1 }
{ Name = "Danial Maze ", Id = 2 }
{ Name = "Danial", Id = 3 }
```

---

```
static string LongestCommonPrefix(IEnumerable<string> xs)
{
    return new string(xs
        .Transpose()
        .TakeWhile(s => s.All(d => d == s.First()))
        .Select(s => s.First())
        .ToArray());
}
```

Comment: How do I get the LongestCommonPrefix from the function? In my edit 1 str == "System.Char[]" I can't seem to get the actual, longest common prefix from out of all the IEnumerables :\

Comment: I've added a `LongestCommonPrefix` method that uses the `Transpose` method from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2070434/76217).

Comment: How do I use the true x.ID for the rather than g.Key? My Ids are being overwritten in real world application

Comment: @Smithy: I'm not sure what you're talking about. Maybe [open a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with an example?

Comment: Sorry, My real world data is in a different language, one I don't speak and I mixed up the columns. Your example is perfect, thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve this by grouping the records on the ID then selecting the first record from each group ordered by the Name length:

```
var result = GetAllGuides.GroupBy(td => td.Id)
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(td => td.Name.Length).First());

foreach (var dude in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{{Name = {0}, Id = {1}}}", dude.Name, dude.Id);
}
```

Comment: That way of getting the name won't quite work as intended in the case of `Danial Maze A` and `Danial Maze B`.