# Using LINQ how to transform a List of Lists using elements index

Tags: c#, linq

using LINQ how can I transform a List of Lists to a new List of Lists where each list has all the elements from the same index.

for example

```
l[0] = {3,15,22,6}
l[1] = {9,81,52,7}
l[2] = {2,0,32,73}
```

will turn into

```
l[0] = {3,9,2}
l[1] = {15,81,0}
l[2] = {22,52,32}
l[3] = {6,7,73}
```

thanks

Comment: I assume the input lists are always going to be the same length? and your output lists in your example seem to have one too many elements (?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this `Transpose` extension method, from [an answer by dtb](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2070434/781792) (I changed the disposing from `Array.ForEach` to `foreach` because I find it clearer, and [I'm not the only one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) who doesn't think `ForEach` methods like that should be used):

```
public static IEnumerable<IList<T>> Transpose<T>(
    this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> source)
{
    var enumerators = source.Select(e => e.GetEnumerator()).ToArray();
    try
    {
        while (enumerators.All(e => e.MoveNext()))
        {
            yield return enumerators.Select(e => e.Current).ToArray();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        foreach (var enumerator in enumerators)
            enumerator.Dispose();
    }
}

// e.g. 
IList<IList<int>> l = new int[3][];
l[0] = new []{0,1,2,3};
l[1] = new []{4,5,6,7};
l[2] = new []{8,9,10,11};
l = l.Transpose().ToList();
// l is { { 0, 4, 8 }, { 1, 5, 9 }, { 2, 6, 10 }, { 3, 7, 11 } }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
source
    .SelectMany(list => list.Select((number, index) => Tuple.Create(number, index)))
    .GroupBy(e => e.Item2)
    .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
    .Select(g => g.Select(e => e.Item1).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var largestIndex=list.Max(x=>x.Count);
  var listSize=list.Count;
  var result=Enumerable.Range(0, largestIndex)
                       .Select(i => Enumerable.Range(0, listSize)
                           .Where(x => i < list[x].Count)
                           .Select(j => list[j][i]));
```