# yield in visual basic

Tags: python, vb.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I implement yield return for IEnumerable functions in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/875587/can-i-implement-yield-return-for-ienumerable-functions-in-vb-net)

How to convert this Python code to VB? Is there any yield method in visual basic? Please help me.

```
 def f(x, y):
        for nx in range(max(0, x-1), min(3, x+2)):
            for ny in range(max(0, y-1), min(3, y+2)):
                yield (nx, ny)
```

Comment: [Not yet.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/875587/can-i-implement-yield-return-for-ienumerable-functions-in-vb-net)

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/97381/yield-in-vb-net and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2912851/what-is-the-equilivant-syntax-in-vb-net-for-yield-return