# Getting started with arcobjects, without aiming to be developer?

Tags: arcgis, arcobjects

What is the best route or place to get started with arcobjects if one is not a developer and not aiming to become one?

I've been using gis professionally for a long time, almost two decades, arcinfo/arcgis for most of that; I'm pretty good. I'm learning software development, and even have a modestly successful small python application used in a public project; I'm not good! I don't want to become a full fledged software developer but I keep running into things I just can't do without programming ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3260344/arcgis-change-feature-class-and-field-aliases-in-bulk/)). In the arcgis world this puts me pretty squarely in the python camp, which is fine by me since I like python, however python does not have straightforward access to arcobjects.

Soooo, I need to get started, but where? [Arcgis help says](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=About_extending_ArcGIS) to get started with the [ESRI Developer Network](http://edn.esri.com/) but $1500/yr is definitely not in my budget, and sounds like using a sledge hammer to swat mosquito. And which language .NET, Visual Basic, or Visual C++?

Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: [ArcObjects API for ArcGIS Desktop—Library Reference](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/arcobjects/ao_start.htm), choose a folder on the left and the you can get the 9.3 object model diagrams. (source: [Stefan Offermann](http://forums.esri.com/thread.asp?t=285247&f=993&c=93) )

Comment: This might be the entrance door I need: [ArcObjects Help for .NET developers](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/Arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have desktop, I'd just install the SDK from the desktop installation DVD's and [download the free VS2010 60 day eval](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb984878.aspx) (which can be extended).

VS Express [is supported](http://resources.arcgis.com./content/arcgissdks/10.0/system-requirements#DeveloperSolutions), but I've never used it.

For language, I'd stay away from C++.  There's more sample code available for C# than VB.NET.  Except for the [yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97381/yield-in-vb-net) keyword, VB.NET and C# are equal.