# VB .Net equivalent for yield break;

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Does VB.Net have an equivealent for c#'s `yield break`?

```vb
Public Function Validate(validationContext As ValidationContext) 
                As IEnumerable(Of ValidationResult) 
                Implements IValidatableObject.Validate
    '' what is equivalent to C#'s - yield break;
End Function
```

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/382189/1341477

Comment: @JimMischel I think he's asking what is the equivalent syntax in VB, not what does it do.

Comment: Yeah, I got trigger happy. According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dscyy5s0.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3, "You can use an Exit Function or Return statement (Visual Basic) or yield break statement (C#) to end the iteration."

Comment: These other questions are not remotely duplicates of this one.

Answer (score 12):

Yield exists in vb.net, as you can see in [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dscyy5s0.aspx)

And you'll even find information on yield break :

> You can use an Exit Function or Return statement (Visual Basic) or
>   yield break statement (C#) to end the iteration.

Comment: After all attempts, compiler is happy with 'Return Nothing'

Comment: If I remember correctly, though, I don't think the actual `Yield` statement was added to VB.NET until .NET 4.5 (Visual Studio 2012).

Comment: No, `Return Nothing` doesn't break the iterator, it returns the default value of the data type, so if your iterator function returns `IEnumerable(Of Integer)` then `Return Nothing` returns 0. Use `Exit Function` to break the iterator.