# What are the differences between C#.net and Visual Basic.net?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, programming-languages

I have a small experience in VB.net and I would like to learn C#.net

What are the differences between VB.net and C#.net?

Is there any difference in performance between these two?

Apart from the syntactical differences, are there any major changes that I have to keep in mind?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the most important functional differences between C# and VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632/what-are-the-most-important-functional-differences-between-c-sharp-and-vb-net)

Answer (score 5):

Performance is equivalent if you write equivalent code, but VB.NET has constructs that are in there for "backward compatibility" which should NEVER be used.  C# doesn't have some of these things.  I'm thinking specifically of:

- Functions which are in the Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace which are members of other standard .NET classes like Trim().  The .NET classes are often faster.
- Redim and Redim Preserve.  Never to be used in .NET, but there they are in VB.
- On Error ... instead of exceptions.  Yuck!
- Late binding (sometimes derisively called "Option Slow").  Not a good idea in a non-dynamic .NET language from a performance perspective.

VB is also missing things like automatic properties which makes it pretty undesirable for me.  Not a performance issue, but worth keeping in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to know about learning C# is that it is not pronounced "C#.net", it is just C#.  Microsoft tacked on ".NET" to VB, because there was a previous version of VB that didn't work on the .NET Framework.  C# was created specifically with the .NET Framework in mind, so the ".net" is implied and unnecessary.  Also as a side note putting "C#.NET" on your resume really tips off a knowledgeable manager to your skill level, or lack there of, regarding C#.

Also [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_C_Sharp_and_Visual_Basic_.NET) is really good for showing the pros and cons as well as the differences between C# and VB.NET at a high level.

Answer (score 1):

Follow following links which give detailed differences

http://www.harding.edu/fmccown/vbnet_csharp_comparison.html

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/vbnet_c__difference.aspx

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308470

In spite of differences as mentioned at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308470 both C# and VB.Net are first class citizens of .Net world

> Although there are differences between
>   Visual Basic .NET and Visual C# .NET,
>   both are first-class programming
>   languages that are based on the
>   Microsoft .NET Framework, and they are
>   equally powerful. Visual Basic .NET is
>   a true object-oriented programming
>   language that includes new and
>   improved features such as inheritance,
>   polymorphism, interfaces, and
>   overloading. Both Visual Basic .NET
>   and Visual C# .NET use the common
>   language runtime. There are almost no
>   performance issues between Visual
>   Basic .NET and Visual C# .NET. Visual
>   C# .NET may have a few more "power"
>   features such as handling unmanaged
>   code, and Visual Basic .NET may be
>   skewed a little toward ease of use by
>   providing features such as late
>   binding. However, the differences
>   between Visual Basic .NET and Visual
>   C# .NET are very small compared to
>   what they were in earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

> No matter which language you select based on your personal preference
>   and past experience, both languages are powerful developer tools and
>   first-class programming languages that share the common language
>   runtime in the .NET Framework.

Says by Microsoft
https://web.archive.org/web/20061027230435/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308470