# What is the difference between C#.Net and VB.Net (Except Syntax)?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Please let me know the difference between C#.Net and VB.Net. I use C#.Net for my projects, but when ever I met with some other programmers they often called VB.Net more powerful and easy, than C#.Net. I always asked them `"Why it is more powerful then C#, since it uses the same framework?"` but still I didn't get any helpful answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523722/what-are-the-differences-between-c-net-and-visual-basic-net

Comment: this should help you get started - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308470

Comment: The features usually get added in both languages though it may not necessarily happen in the same release. VB.Net is considered easier to pick for a developer with prior experience in VB6. For a new developer either language should prove equally easy/difficult to work with.

Comment: Often VB is considered an easier language to learn, but that is in part because the syntax is less strict and it conceals some core programming concepts from the programmer. While this makes it easier to learn, it can also make mistakes less obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Pointers (C#)
- XML literals (VB.NET)
- VB6 leftovers (VB.NET)
- A few other syntax differences

In the end, not a whole lot. Although, some say C# programmers are better paid (never looked into it, but it's possible).

It also depends on your definition of 'powerful' and 'easy'. Both are powerful at their jobs. C# may have a slight advantage in terms of performance since it has pointers.. but they are rarely used in most cases.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think I've ever seen a real-world c# program with a pointer in it. If you need something that low-level, you might be better off using c++.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, there is no difference except the syntax. Both use the Common Language Runtime ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime)) ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ddk909ch%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)). They are just two different languages that use the same libraries, and actually compile to the same thing. This is one of the reasons you can write a library in VB.net, compile it to a dll, and include that dll in a c# program.

There are some small differences, but for the most part, the choice of one over the other is almost entirely personal preference. Personally, I find the c# syntax to be less prone to errors, but some people like the "english-ness" of VB.

Comment: This is not true, VB.net has XML literals and C# does not. There are other things, but this is the first that springs to mind.

Answer (score -1):

It's the same thing. I don't even know why Microsoft have C# and VB since it really does the same things.

Comment: This is not true, VB.net has XML literals and C# does not. There are other things, but this is the first that springs to mind.