# Differences between VB.NET and VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I have few questions in mind. I am new to this field of Visual Basic so don't make fun of me.

1.) What are the differences between `VB.NET` and `VB`?
2.) I need to develop basic apps for Windows.(like a notepad) Which one should I use?
3.) Is there an IDE available for both?
4.) If possible can you suggest me a good resource for learning VB or VB.NET.

**Note:** I know C and Java. I couldn't find a satisfactory answer anywhere.
Stackoverflow always provides the most precise answers.

Comment: It's more important to check for differences between C#.NET and VB.NET and choose one of them. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434825/vb-net-vs-c-net

Comment: "It would be better to think of Visual Basic.NET as an interface to .NET rather than a continuation of Visual Basic" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Visual_Basic_and_Visual_Basic_.NET

Comment: Microsoft does not call it "VB.NET" any longer, so this could be confusing since you're new to this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> 1.) What are the differences between VB.NET and VB?

VB.NET is a modern, object-oriented language. VB (Classic) is its predecessor, and it's no longer actively maintained.

I don't know if that is what you are looking for, but a technical comparison can be found in Wikipedia:

- [Comparison of Visual Basic and Visual Basic .NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Visual_Basic_and_Visual_Basic_.NET)

> 2.) I need to develop basic apps for Windows.(like a notepad) Which one should I use?

VB.NET. However, if you already know Java, the C# syntax might be more familiar to you. From a functional point of view, [VB.NET and C# are almost equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11632/87698).

> 3.) Is there an IDE available for both?

VB.NET applications can be developed with Visual Studio, the most recent version is 2013.

The VB Classic IDE is unsupported as of April 8, 2008.

> 4.) If possible can you suggest me a good resource for learning VB or VB.NET

This is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

What is the difference between VB and VB.NET?

Now VB.NET is object-oriented language. The following are some of the differences:

Data Type Changes

The .NET platform provides Common Type System to all the supported languages. This means that all the languages must support the same data types as enforced by common language runtime. This eliminates data type incompatibilities between various languages. For example on the 32-bit Windows platform, the integer data type takes 4 bytes in languages like C++ whereas in VB it takes 2 bytes. Following are the main changes related to data types in VB.NET:

. Under .NET the integer data type in VB.NET is also 4 bytes in size.
. VB.NET has no currency data type. Instead it provides decimal as a replacement.
. VB.NET introduces a new data type called Char. The char data type takes 2 bytes and can store Unicode characters.
. VB.NET do not have Variant data type. To achieve a result similar to variant type you can use Object data type. (Since every thing in .NET including primitive data types is an object, a variable of object type can point to any data type).
. In VB.NET there is no concept of fixed length strings.
. In VB6 we used the Type keyword to declare our user-defined structures. VB.NET introduces the structure keyword for the same purpose.
for more details you can refer http://dev.fyicenter.com/Interview-Questions/dotNet-1/What_is_the_difference_between_VB_and_VB_NET_.html

and to develop windows apps , my best language is C#  and you can choose VB.NET too

Comment: Or you can refer to http://dev.fyicenter.com/Interview-Questions/dotNet-1/What_is_the_difference_between_VB_and_VB_NET_.html

Answer (score -2):

```
vb                                                vb.net
```

1. it is interpreter based language.              it is compiled language,use the cls.
2. not a type safe language.                      it is a safe type language.
3. backward compatible.                           not backward compatible.